# NextJS hot reload does not work for the backend

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js, backend, hot-reload

I have been working with nextjs for a little now and I have noticed that the backend side does not hot reload when I make changes to the API, is there a particular configuration to make hot reload happen also for the backend? I have searched around the internet and found nothing about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a library such as **nodemon** or **pm2**.

```bash
npm i -D nodemon
```

Then in your `package.json` add this script:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --watch pages --exec next dev"
  }
}
```